# How to use local and instance variables to improve the application design of a program

Tags: php, instance-variables, local-variables

I understand that local variables are limited to the scope they were declared in and instance variables exist as long as the object exists. But suppose I have two classes:

PersonalInformation.php

```
<?php

class PersonalInformation {

    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $gender;
    private $birthday;

    function getName(){...}
    function setName(){...}

    //Other getter and setter

}
```

and PersonalInformationController.php which takes the input from a form, istantiate a PersonalInformation object and set its attributes:

```
class PersonalInformationController {

    private $personalInformation;

    function __construct() {
        $this->personalInformation = new PersonalInformation();
    }

    function doPost() {
        $this->setPersonalDetails();
        $this->setResidence();
        $this->setContact();
    }

    private function setPersonalDetails() {

        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
        $surname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "surname");
        $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender");
        $birthday = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "birthday");
        $nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nationality");


        if (empty($name) || empty($surname)) {
            throw new RequiredFieldException("Name and surname can't be empty");
        } else if (!is_string($name) || !is_string($surname)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Input must be a string!');         
        } else {
            $this->personalInformation->setName($name);
            $this->personalInformation->setSurname($surname);
        }

        if (!empty($gender) && is_string($gender)) {
            $this->personalInformation->setGender($gender);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Input must be a string!');       
       }

         if (!empty($birthday) && is_string($birthday)) {
        $this->personalInformation->setBirthday($birthday);
        }
        if (!empty($nationality) && is_string($nationality)) {
            $this->personalInformation->setNationality($nationality);
        }
    }

    private function setResidence() {
        $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "address");
        $zipCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "zipCode");
        $city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "city");
        $nation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nation");

        if (!empty($address) && is_string($address)) {
            $this->personalInformation->setAddress($address);
        }

        //...//
    }

    private function setContact() { ... }
}
```

This class have three main methods (setPersonalDetails() - setResidence() - setContact()) which take the input from a form, in the html page, put them in local variables (that is, $name, $surname etc..) and check on type in order to set them in the PersonalInformation object.

Here my question: "From point of view of code design(especially extensibility and readability), there exists some differences between the use of these local variables or declare them as instance variables in order to leave the three methods only for checking the type of these variables (and not take the input) ?" . And so make something like that:

```
class PersonalInformationController {

    private $personalInformation;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $gender;
    private $birthday;
    private $nationality;
    private $cellphone;
    //Other instance variables


    function __construct() {
        $this->personalInformation = new PersonalInformation();
    }

    function doPost() {
        $name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name");
        $surname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "surname");
        $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender");
        $birthday = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "birthday");
        $nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nationality");
        //...
        $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "address");
        $zipCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "zipCode");
        $city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "city");
        $nation = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nation");
    }

    private function setPersonalDetails() {
    // NOW THIS METHOD ONLY CHECKS THE TYPE OF THE INPUT
        if (empty($this->name) || empty($this->surname)) {
            throw new RequiredFieldException("Name and surname can't be empty");
        } else if (!is_string($this->name) || !is_string($this->surname)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Input must be a string!');         
        } else {
            $this->personalInformation->setName($this->name);
            $this->personalInformation->setSurname($this->surname);
        }

        if (!empty($this->gender) && is_string($this->gender)) {
            $this->personalInformation->setGender($this->gender);
        } else {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Input must be a string!');       
       }

         if (!empty($this->birthday) && is_string($this->birthday)) {
        $this->personalInformation->setBirthday($this->birthday);
        }
        if (!empty($this->nationality) && is_string($this->nationality)) {
            $this->personalInformation->setNationality($this->nationality);
        }
    }

   //setResidence() and setContact() are like the previous method.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be more related to application design than performance.

Instead of contemplating the performance of local vs instance variables, consider the purpose of each variable, and ask yourself `Does it belong here?`. Classes can become quite large. In the end, you only want to store as much information as is necessary.

### Instance Variables (also known as class *"properties"*)

Instance variables are properties of an object (name, birthday, width, height, etc). They either describe an object or contain information that the object must know about. Variables that do not meet one of those requirements should **not** be an instance variable. Instead, you can pass them into your methods as parameters.

### Local Variables

In object-oriented applications, local variables are generally limited to the scope of the function (aka *method*) that they reside in. These variables are usually destroyed or are no longer used after the function finishes executing.

### Domain Objects

Your application contains a domain object called `PersonalInformation`. A domain object has a single purpose: to store information about a `thing` or `abstract thing` (such as personal information). Therefore, it should only contain properties, such as `name, surname, birthday, ...`, and method that directly manipulate those properties, such as getters and setters.

The domain object is also where you should place your validation logic. If you use the `PersonalInformation` object in multiple controllers, you will find yourself rewriting the same input validation rules across many files. This can be avoided by setting values to the properties of the object, and then validating them internally through a `validate()` method.

By doing this, your validation logic can be removed from your controller.

### Controllers

Controllers are meant to accept requests, tell other parts of the application to process POST/DELETE/PUT data, and then either render a view (such as a HTML template or JSON string) or redirect to another part of the application.

In *most cases*, your controllers **should not** handle validation logic for your domain objects.

### Refactoring your code

I've refactored your code to meet these principles, and added comments to explain the purpose for the changes as I made them.

### PersonalInformationController.php

```
<?php

class PersonalInformationController
{
    /**
     * Though this controller interacts with one or more PersonalInformation objects, those objects
     * do not describe this controller. Nor do they provide any additional information that the
     * controller MUST know about.
     *
     * This variable should be local, not a class property.
     */
    //private $personalInformation;

    /**
     * Because $personalInformation is no longer a class property,
     * it does not need to be set in the constructor.
     */
    function __construct() {}

    function doPost()
    {
        /**
         * The try/catch block will catch any validation exceptions thrown by the validate()
         * method withing the $personalInformation object.
         */
        try {
            /**
             * This instance of the PersonalInformation object is only being used within the scope of
             * this function, so it should be a local variable.
             *
             * @var PersonalInformation personalInformation
             */
            $personalInformation = new PersonalInformation();
            $personalInformation->setName(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "name"));
            $personalInformation->setSurname(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "surname"));
            $personalInformation->setGender(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "gender"));
            $personalInformation->setBirthday(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "birthday"));
            $personalInformation->setNationality(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "nationality"));
            /** Set other properties of personalInformation ... */

            /**
             * This validate() method will check the integrity of the data you passed into the setter
             * methods above. If any of the domain object's properties are invalid, an exception will be thrown.
             */
            $personalInformation->validate();

            /** save the object / show view / other controller logic */

        } catch(RequiredFieldException $e) {
            /** A field was empty. Error handling logic here. */
        } catch(InvalidFieldException $e) {
            /** A field value was incorrect. Error handling logic here. */
        }
    }
}
```

### PersonalInformation.php (domain object)

```
/**
 * Class PersonalInformation
 * 
 * This class is a domain object. Notice that it only contains properties that describe PersonalInformation.
 * All of the logic contained in this class manipulates the properties, and is "unaware" of any outside entities.
 */
class PersonalInformation {

    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $gender;
    private $birthday;
    private $nationality;

    /**
     * Try to avoid duplicate code. If all the validation for your domain object is the same,
     * use a method, such as this, to store all of the validation logic.
     * 
     * @throws \InvalidFieldException
     * @throws \RequiredFieldException
     */
    public function validate() {
        if(empty($this->name) || empty($this->surname)) {
            throw new RequiredFieldException("Name and surname can't be empty");
        } else if(!is_string($this->name) || !is_string($this->surname)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Name and surname must be a strings!');
        }

        if(empty($this->gender) || !is_string($this->gender)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Gender must be a string!');
        }

        if(empty($this->birthday) || !is_string($this->birthday)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Birthday must be a string!');
        }

        if(empty($this->nationality) || !is_string($this->nationality)) {
            throw new InvalidFieldException('Nationality must be a string!');
        }

        /** other validation rules **/
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $surname
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getGender()
    {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $gender
     */
    public function setGender($gender)
    {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBirthday()
    {
        return $this->birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $birthday
     */
    public function setBirthday($birthday)
    {
        $this->birthday = $birthday;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getNationality()
    {
        return $this->nationality;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $nationality
     */
    public function setNationality($nationality)
    {
        $this->nationality = $nationality;
    }
}
```

Notice that the application is now using less variables and functions. It only stores as much information as is necessary in each class. Therefore, your application will experience better performance and use less memory. The code is clean, simple, and easy to maintain.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @MParson, it's a really clear answer. It's all clear to me, but what if the controller should check the length of each field (like strln($name) > 0 && strln($name)<= 30) , etc.? These checks must stay in the domain object? Because I thought that the controller should check this kind of things whereas the PersonalInformation's setters only have to check the kind of the field (string/boolean/int etc.) which is an intrinsic properties of the instance variable.

Comment: The purpose of input validation is to enforce the integrity of your application's data. In this case, your application expects all of your `PersonalInformation` objects to contain a `name` that has a string value with 1 to 30 characters. Because that validation requirement is tied to the object and not the controller, it should go inside of the domain object.

Comment: There are some cases where a validation rule does not belong to the domain object. For example, most user registration forms have `password` and `confirm_password` fields. Both fields must match, but your `user` object probably doesn't have a `confirm_password` field. Depending on the design of your application, it may be acceptable to place that logic in the controller, because you are comparing a domain object property (`password`) to a piece of data (`confirm_password') that is specific to that controller method's form.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Though your question was more related to design than performance, I still highly recommend reading through @helmbert's answer as well. Premature optimization can lead to unnecessary design constraints and headaches. Focus on building the application with an extensible design. Then figure out if optimization is needed.

Comment: you right. May I should change the Title. What I meant was right what you said.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

To me, this smells of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Optimizations like these will shave of a few microseconds at the most; in PHP applications where each request may take a few hundred milliseconds to complete, this is hardly worth the effort.

#### Long answer

I've created a short [PhpBench](https://github.com/phpbench/phpbench) benchmark to test this. The test script simply counts up a local variable, and a class instance variable 1 million times:

```
/**
 * @Revs(16)
 * @Iterations(1)
 */
class VariableAccess
{
  private $var = 0;

  public function benchLocalVar()
  {
    $var = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i ++) {
      $var ++;
    }
  }

  public function benchInstanceVar()
  {
    $this->var = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i ++) {
      $this->var ++;
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the results:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpbench run test.php --report=default
PhpBench 0.11-dev (@git_sha@). Running benchmarks.

\VariableAccess

    benchLocalVar                 I0 P0     [μ Mo]/r: 111,398.125 111,398.125 (μs)  [μSD μRSD]/r: 0.000μs 0.00%
    benchInstanceVar              I0 P0     [μ Mo]/r: 96,092.250 96,092.250 (μs)    [μSD μRSD]/r: 0.000μs 0.00%

2 subjects, 2 iterations, 32 revs, 0 rejects
(best [mean mode] worst) = 96,092.250 [103,745.188 103,745.188] 96,092.250 (μs)
⅀T: 207,490.375μs μSD/r 0.000μs μRSD/r: 0.000%
suite: 1339fa11bf3f46fe629a65f838db6a37419e7cfe, date: 2016-04-17, stime: 16:20:01
+----------------+------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-----+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
| benchmark      | subject          | groups | params | revs | iter | rej | mem      | time          | z-value | diff    |
+----------------+------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-----+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
| VariableAccess | benchLocalVar    |        | []     | 16   | 0    | 0   | 273,240b | 111,398.125μs | 0.00σ   | +13.74% |
| VariableAccess | benchInstanceVar |        | []     | 16   | 0    | 0   | 273,296b | 96,092.250μs  | 0.00σ   | 0.00%   |
+----------------+------------------+--------+--------+------+------+-----+----------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

In this benchmark, using instance variables is actually faster than using local variables. However, we're talking about 15 **micro**seconds for one million iterations!

### And the moral of this story...

Don't let premature optimization influence the design of your program. Do not sacrifice readability or extensible design just for some obscure performance optimization, unless you know for sure that you're having a performance bottleneck at that particular piece of code.

Comment: Thank you. May I wrote the wrong title. What I meant was how to improve the design of my application. However your answer is good to me, I never considered what you just said before, so I'll take it in mind :)